# Error in Chrome only - 'Cannot read property ' toLowerCase' to null

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Is there something in the code below that is making Chrome throw an error? IE and Firefox wouldn't accept postcode inputs with spaces without the additional code, but now that I've added:

`strPostcode = strPostcode.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '')`

Chrome won't accept postcodes in an input container and is returning 'Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of NULL. Can anyone shed some light on this error, especially as it's only Chrome that is returning it??

```
// ****************** Event Listners ***************************************************
var myload = map.on("load", loadHandler);

function loadHandler(evt) {
    createTOC();
    myload.remove();
    var strPostcode = GetQueryStringParams('postcode');
    if (strPostcode) {
        strPostcode = strPostcode.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '')

        $('#txtsearch').val(strPostcode);
        $('.btnSearch').trigger('click');
        // PostcodeSearch(strPostcode);
    }
}

map.on('update-end', function () {

    LocalAuthoritySearch();

    //debugger;
    if (currURL && currLayerId && currField) {
        //addLayertoMap(currURL, currLayerId, currField);
        addFields(currURL, currLayerId, currField, currTOCid);
    }

});

map.addLayer(baseMapServiceLayer);
```

Comment: Where are you getting this exception? I mean, at which line?

Comment: I think it's here, at the start of the code:

Comment: map = new Map("map", {
        logo: false,
     
    });
   
    initLayer();
    baseMapServiceLayer = new my.Basemap();